# C#/AS3 How do I create a public global data object that any other object can read, but only certain objects can set?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3

Here is the conundrum.  I have a specific set of state variables that are used in almost every supporting object I have, and I want those variables to be able to be read by any object that needs to read them, but I want to protect them so that only 1 object has the ability to set them.

For example, lets say I am making a poker game.  Variables like:
- Minimum Ante
- Maximum Bet
- Maximum Number of Players
- Current GameState (Placing Bets, Shuffling, Dealing, Paying, etc.)

Personally, I prefer small compact component classes, so lets say I have the majority of the poker game logic in 1 controller class, but i have 50 supporting objects that handle everything that isn't the poker game logic itself, such as a PlayerInterface, a graphics controller, 'The Deck' to handle shuffle and deal logic, etc.  Alot of my smaller support classes need to see what the minimum ante is, and the current method I am using is for the controller class to pass these variables into the supporting classes as parameters.

The obvious downside to this is I have 50 supporting objects all holding on to their own local variables for minimum ante to hold the same information that I am passing to them from the controller.  Wasted parameters, memory, and opens a ton of risk if any of those variables ever get out of sync.

So, how to I make these variables global so everyone can access and read them?  The knee jerk reactionary answer is some public static variables, however this presents the problem that anyone could also write to them.  Not only do I not want my supporting objects having the power to change the minimum ante without the controller's knowledge, but I also don't want the client shell that holds the poker game to be able to change them without first going through the proper checks contained in the controller.

So what do I do?  Someone once mentioned to me the idea of a Singleton, but after plenty of research, most of it a few years old or more, I found about a 50/50 split in the community who say Singletons are a good idea vs those who think they aren't.

If not singletons or statics, then what?  I am open to any ideas to research and try out.

Remember, I want any object, anytime, anywhere to be able to GET the data it needs, but only a very specific object to have the ability to SET the data, should it need to change, so that it can filter through the proper checks.  By proper checks, I mean for example in the poker game, if a player has the ability to change the Minimum Bet on the table, he should only be able to do so between hands, or before a tournament begins.  I don't want him messing with these things during play.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: show some of your existing code.  I'm not sure what the issue here is - is your code C# or AS3?  How is your application used? Online? Desktop/Mobile App?  If you are in control of all the code, why are you concerned?    Seems like a simple solution,  keep the variable inside your controller and privately declared (so only the controller can access that variable), then on the same controller, create a public function or public getter function to read the value of the private var - make them Static if you want a lazy way to read it.

Comment: I put both C# and AS3 because I develop apps for both Mobile platforms (C#) and Web/Flash versions (AS3).  Preferably, whatever the solution may be, I would like it to work for both platforms, since I try to keep the code in both platforms as identical as language syntax allows.  I am not in control of all the code, the game is just 1 component of the app, which is why I want to limit access.  Other components not under my control need to be able to read the data, but not have the ability to set it.  Another issue with static functions and variables is they limit your instances to 1.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use interfaces approach here.

Declare two interfaces as

```
public interface IReadOnlyAccess
{
     int Property{get;}
}

public interface IFullAccess
{
     int Property{get;set;}
}
```

Then your class would implement both interfaces like

```
public interface MyClass: IReadOnlyAccess, IFullAccess
{
     public int Property{get;set;}
}
```

Then wherever you need full access you get it via IFullAccess, if otherwise - via IReadOnlyAccess.

Comment: Interesting.  So in my case, all of my supporting objects would only implement the ReadOnly interface.  That part makes sense, However, I am still relatively new to interfaces, if every object that implements these interfaces has to implement the Property, then how do I link all the different implementations of that property to the same variable?

Comment: Read about interfaces. In general read some general books on topic like Richter on .net framework.

Comment: @DSalis properties with same names will be mapped to the same fields seamlessly.

Comment: I have a slot machine for this example.  First, I interfaced the BetInformation like you said:
`    public interface IBetInformationWrite
    {
        long DefaultBetPerLine { get; set; }
    }`
`public interface IBetInformationRead
    {
        long DefaultBetPerLine { get; }
    }`
Now I have 2 more interfaces, one that should have write access, the other should not:
`public interface ISlotGame : IBetInformationWrite
    {
        void SetDefaultBetPerLine(long newBetPerLine);
    }`
`interface IReelSet:IBetInformationRead
    {
        void DoSomeStuff();
    }`

Comment: Damn that looks like crap.  How do I get the nice code blocks like your example has?  I am brand new to the site.

Comment: Anyhow, I built a couple of dummy classes that use those interfaces, and it appears to be working correctly.  The TestReelSet cannot set DefaultBetPerLine, but the TestSlotGame can, which is exactly what I want.  However, my TestClient (aka, the rest of the app that holds on to the SlotGame as a member variable, as well as all the other stuff in the app) can still set the property directly by calling MySlotGame.DefaultBetPerLine = 0;  However, I can't make the property or setter protected without pissing off the compiler.

Comment: What do you mean by pissing the compiler off?

Answer (score 0):

Make an inner class, it will have access to the main classes private vars:

```
public class OuterClass
{
    public string StringProperty { get; private set; }
    public  InnerClass CreateInnerClass()
    {
        InnerClass ic = new InnerClass(this);
        return ic;
    }
    public class InnerClass
    {
        private OuterClass _outer;
        public InnerClass(OuterClass oc)
        {
            _outer = oc;
        }

        public string Prop
        {
            get
            {
                return _outer.StringProperty ;
            }
            set
            {
                _outer.StringProperty = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So create the main class that most people have readonly access:

```
var oc = new OuterClass();
oc.StringProperty = "123";   <-- not allowed, is `readonly`
```

To write to properties, create inner class instance:

```
var oc = new OuterClass();
var ic = oc.CreateInnerClass();
ic.StringProperty = "123";
```

Comment: In this example, how would the children of the OuterClass gain access to the variables?  For example, the PokerGame(OuterClass) might have a CardDeck object that handles shuffling and dealing, but the CardDeck would not have a PokerGame contained in it, so it can't just PokerGame.SomeProperty to get the information it needs.

Comment: if you understand the concept then you should try it out.  There are even more secure techniques, this is a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the cleanest, easiest solution is to have everything done in your controller class.

Let's say something like this:

AS3:

```
//adding the final keyword, locks this class so others can't extent/inherit from it
public final class MyController {

    //create a privately scoped var (it can only be accessed in this class)
    private var minBet:Number = 0;

    //create a public getter that can be read by any class/object
    public function get minimumBet():Number {
        return minBet;
    }

    private function set minimumBet(value:Number):void {
        //do you checks etc
        minBet = value;
    }
}
```

C#

```
//sealed in C# is the same as final in AS3
public sealed class MyController
{
    private float minBet = 0;

    public float minimumBet
    {
        get { return minBet; }
    }
}
```

---

```
instanceOfMyController.minBet //will throw an error
instanceOfMyController.minimumBet = 10; //will throw an error
instanceOfMyController.minimumBet //will supply the value of the minBet var
```

If you're doing a lot cross-language code, consider checking out something like [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) which can compile out to AS3 or C# with the same code.